# Better representation of a recursive polymorhphic type structure

Tags: recursion, types, polymorphism, ocaml

I am implementing a tree. During the execution of my program data gets added to the node.

The code below shows my first implementation:

```
type 'a tree =
  | Node of 'a
  | Leaf

type nodata_node =
  {
    b: nodata_node tree;
  }

type data_node =
  {
    a: int;
    b: data_node tree;
  }
```

The problem with this implementation is that I can't represent the value `b` in the following snippet:

```
let a = { b = Node { b = Leaf } }

let b = { b = Node { a = 1; b = Leaf } }
```

I need to be able to represent a `node` that doesn't have `data` but whose children all do.

So I came up with the following implementation:

```
type _ data =
  | Unknown : unit -> unit data
  | SomeInt : int -> int data

type 'a tree =
  | Node of ('a, 'a) node
  | Leaf

and ('a, 'b) node =
  {
    a: 'a data;
    b: 'b tree;
  }

let a = { a = Unknown (); b = Node { a = Unknown (); b = Leaf } }

let b = { a = Unknown (); b = Node { a = SomeInt 1; b = Leaf } }
```

That works, but it seems a bit clunky to have a field that is empty at first and gets filled later. I was wondering if there was a way to have a representation equivalent to the second but with a solution similar to the first one, in that a node with no data is not represented by a structure with en empty data field.

EDIT:
I realise now that my use of GADT is not bringing much to the question I am asking, so, here is simpler version of my second attempt:

```
type 'a tree =
  | Node of ('a, 'a) node
  | Leaf

and ('a, 'b) node =
  {
    a: 'a;
    b: 'b tree;
  }

let a = { a = (); b = Node { a = (); b = Leaf } }

let b = { a = (); b = Node { a = 1; b = Leaf } }
```

EDIT2: I guess there is a way to do it with functors and mutually recursive definition. I am interested in a solution that does not rely on functors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to keep the `'a tree` type constructor, you could go for:

```
type 'a tree =
  | Node of 'a
  | Leaf
type child_node = {data:int; x: child; y:child}
and child = child_node tree
type parent = child tree

let x: parent = Node (Node {data=0; x=Leaf; y = Leaf})
```